# TypeScript pipe/map error - TS2322 Type Observable<{} | User> is not assignable to Observable<User>

Tags: angular, typescript

I've inherited an Angular 6 project and getting errors that I can't quite work out.

The problematic code is:

```
public UpdateUser(request: UpdateUserRequest): Observable<User> {
  this._spinner.show();
  return this.http.put<User>(`${API.USER.CRUD}/${request.id}`, request)
  .pipe(
    map((result) => {
        this._spinner.hide();
        this._toastr.success(SUCCESS.USER_UPDATE);
        return result;
    }),
    catchError((err: ErrorResponse) => {
        if (err && err.error && err.error.errors) {
        err.error.errors.map(m => this._toastr.error(m));
        }
        throw err;
  }));
}
```

The errors returned are:

> error TS2322: Type
>   'Observable<{} | User>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. 
>   Type '{} | User' is not assignable to type 'User'.
>       Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'User'.
>         Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.
>
> error TS2322: Type
>   'Observable<{} | User>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

If I remove from `.pipe` onwards, this is fine, so I'm sure the problem is in the map/piping, but not really sure where?

Comment: Do you need the UpdateUser method to have a return type of Observable<User>? Are you subscribing to this method anywhere? I assume if you remove the  Observable<User> return type from your function definition the error goes away. The pipe method returns an observable that doesnt match the return type. When you dont pipe you're just returning an Observable<User> which is what you're saying you expect.

Comment: try to cast the result variable to `User` like so `return result as User;`